# How to write files with UIDcomentBrowserViewController

Tags: ios, uidocumentbrowservc, uidocumentbrowserviewcontroller

Is where a way to **read/write** multiple files in **UIDocumentBrowserViewController**.

Recently, I know UIDocumentBrowserViewController as rootViewController can read files. But how to **write** files.

For example, i want to read zip file and then unzip it to current folder.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentbrowserviewcontroller/2927800-importdocument ?

Comment: @Paulw11 You save my time, Thanks a lot!